# Xamarin iOS crash

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have submitted my app to apple for review and they are reporting this crash at startup - i do not see this in both the simulator and my real device, could anyone shed any light on what could be causing it.

I have symobilcated the crash, but parts still appear missing :

```
    {"app_name":"SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS","timestamp":"2020-06-04 14:07:54.00 -0700","app_version":"1.0.8","slice_uuid":"ecc0205f-d4d6-33d8-91db-92796b30d087","adam_id":1514389694,"build_version":"1.0.8","bundleID":"SSNC.Mobile.DI","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)","incident_id":"BC5899E0-471E-42E3-9D5B-F38B6B94607C","name":"SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS"}
Incident Identifier: BC5899E0-471E-42E3-9D5B-F38B6B94607C
CrashReporter Key:   733ab9cd5376806dbd8128fcdf7f1f1928a4a9f6
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS [393]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F2D03BD8-E209-4094-A1AA-CD5BF63632A7/SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS.app/SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS
Identifier:          SSNC.Mobile.DI
Version:             1.0.8 (1.0.8)
AppStoreTools:       11E608a
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           SSNC.Mobile.DI [536]


Date/Time:           2020-06-04 14:07:54.0902 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-06-04 14:07:52.8741 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.06.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_407  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019736edf0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019728e930 pthread_kill + 228
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019721cc24 __abort + 116
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019721cbb0 __abort + 0
4   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001052cfcf0 xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread + 40252
5   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001052c4f2c xamarin_get_block_descriptor + 7812
6   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010518a938 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42592568 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40959580
7   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010511f970 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42154352 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40521364
8   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010511e358 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42148696 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40515708
9   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105114138 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42107192 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40474204
10  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102e949ec plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 5933548 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4300560
11  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102c2714c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 3387724 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1754736
12  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102c2ded4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 3415764 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1782776
13  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102f6bb2c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 6814508 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 5181520
14  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102e542f0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 5669616 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4036628
15  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105131570 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42227056 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40594068
16  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051eca4c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42994252 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41361264
17  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051f02b0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43008688 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41375700
18  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102a7f818 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1652760 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 19772
19  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102a805ec plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1656300 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 23312
20  Foundation                      0x0000000197980d6c __NSThreadPerformPerform + 188
21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197503af4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000197503a48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001975031fc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 296
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001974fdf38 __CFRunLoopRun + 796
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001974fd8f4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a1914604 GSEventRunModal + 164
27  UIKitCore                       0x000000019b6d1358 UIApplicationMain + 1944
28  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102fc4748 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 7178056 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 5545068
29  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102f1b830 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 6486064 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4853076
30  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102f1b7b4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 6485940 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4852952
31  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102ab4de4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1871332 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 238344
32  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102e542f0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 5669616 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4036628
33  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105131570 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42227056 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40594068
34  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051eca4c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42994252 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41361264
35  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051f2ca4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43019428 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41386440
36  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010510fb28 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42089256 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40456268
37  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001052cc92c xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread + 27000
38  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102ab4d44 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 1871172 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 238184
39  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001973792dc start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  SGen worker
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019736ebc0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972911e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 680
2   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010528fdfc plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43662844 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 42029856
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019728d8fc _pthread_start + 168
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:  Finalizer
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019734c7c0 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010518dcbc plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42605756 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40972768
2   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523aa1c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313692 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680704
3   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523a8a0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313312 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680324
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019728d8fc _pthread_start + 168
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959d4 thread_start + 8



Thread 8 name:  Timer-Scheduler
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019736ebc0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972911e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 680
2   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010529f734 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43726644 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 42093656
3   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105246094 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43360404 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41727416
4   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105245f6c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43360108 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41727120
5   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105246190 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43360656 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41727668
6   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105234f78 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43290488 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41657500
7   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051af320 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42742560 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41109572
8   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bba878 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2943096 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1310108
9   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bba3e4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2941924 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1308936
10  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb9eec plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2940652 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1307664
11  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb9e9c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2940572 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1307584
12  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb9cbc plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2940092 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1307104
13  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb9e08 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2940424 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1307436
14  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bbd304 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2953988 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1321000
15  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb3d5c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2915676 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1282688
16  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb160c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2905612 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1272624
17  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb140c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2905100 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1272112
18  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb1390 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2904976 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1271988
19  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb3ec4 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2916036 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1283048
20  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102e542f0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 5669616 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4036628
21  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105131570 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42227056 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40594068
22  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051eca4c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42994252 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41361264
23  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051f2338 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43017016 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41384028
24  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523ab14 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313940 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680952
25  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523a8a0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313312 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680324
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019728d8fc _pthread_start + 168
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 9 name:  tid_9e03
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019736ebc0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972911e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 680
2   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010529f734 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43726644 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 42093656
3   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001052a8414 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43762708 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 42129720
4   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010522ec0c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43265036 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41632048
5   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523aa1c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313692 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680704
6   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523a8a0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313312 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680324
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019728d8fc _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 10 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019736ebc0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972911e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 680
2   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010529f75c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43726684 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 42093696
3   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105246094 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43360404 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41727416
4   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105245f6c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43360108 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41727120
5   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051deda0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42937760 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41304772
6   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051ad904 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42735876 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41102888
7   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb3448 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2913352 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1280364
8   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb3500 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2913536 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1280548
9   SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb2f7c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2912124 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1279136
10  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb2fd0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2912208 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1279220
11  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102badb28 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2890536 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1257548
12  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bad88c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2889868 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1256880
13  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010312b0e0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 8646880 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 7013892
14  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010312aed8 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 8646360 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 7013372
15  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010312ae0c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 8646156 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 7013168
16  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000104f3f988 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 40188296 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 38555308
17  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000104f7e290 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 40444560 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 38811572
18  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000104f3f2a0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 40186528 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 38553540
19  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bc2778 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2975608 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1342620
20  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bc7f34 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2998068 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1365080
21  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bc81a8 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2998696 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1365708
22  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb160c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2905612 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1272624
23  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb140c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2905100 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1272112
24  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bcc488 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 3015816 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1382828
25  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bc80c0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2998464 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1365476
26  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bc7f98 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2998168 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1365180
27  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb6b38 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2927416 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1294428
28  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102ef7900 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 6338816 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4705828
29  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102bb8bf8 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 2935800 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 1302812
30  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000102e542f0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 5669616 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 4036628
31  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x0000000105131570 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 42227056 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 40594068
32  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001051ee368 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43000680 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41367692
33  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x00000001052319a8 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43276712 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41643724
34  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010522f284 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43266692 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41633704
35  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523aa1c plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313692 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680704
36  SSNC.Mobile.DI.iOS              0x000000010523a8a0 plcrash::MS::async::dwarf_cfa_state_iterator<unsigned long long, long long>::next+ 43313312 (unsigned int*, plcrash::MS::async::plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_t*, unsigned long long*) + 41680324
37  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019728d8fc _pthread_start + 168
38  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001972959d4 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000039   x7: 0x0000000000000600
    x8: 0x00000000000005b9   x9: 0x29d6874f1ce81ffa  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000bf3d01
   x12: 0x0000000106d80000  x13: 0x0000000000004009  x14: 0x0000000106d80000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x00000001d930e808  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x0000000105b05960  x22: 0x0000000105d071a0  x23: 0x0000000106829f50
   x24: 0x000000010e130940  x25: 0x000000010788ace0  x26: 0x0000000106828600  x27: 0x0000000000000009
   x28: 0x0000000102e542ef   fp: 0x000000016d5104b0   lr: 0x000000019728e930
    sp: 0x000000016d510490   pc: 0x000000019736edf0 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the symbolicated logs, there isn't much info in most cases. I really don't see anything useful here too. Do you have some global error handling added? If no, I suggest you add one and look through the logs there.

Comment: Yes, and its hooked up to appcenter - but its not getting that far by the looks of it.
And only fails when we send to apple and they try it, so cant recreate locally.

Comment: Have updated with more symbolification

Comment: There is no useful information in stack trace , and we can't help more if you are not able to reproduce the issue on your side .

Comment: Have a look how to symbolicate a crash log [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579117/how-to-symbolicate-crash-error-logs-from-a-xamarin-forms-ios-project)

Comment: How you tried to build the app on your device in the release configuration?