# Xamarin IOS app, iCloud restore doesn't work once on App Store

Tags: ios, xamarin, icloud

My IOS app is now on the Apple App Store. I tested it like crazy before it was put on the App Store and I am sure Apple did as well, but now that it is on the App Store, when I install it from there, the restore function I wrote to restore the applications data from iCloud does not work. The backup function works, as I can see the iCloud usage on my phone for my app contains 78mb of data, but the restore does not work at all, it just goes back to the home page. I have no idea why as I get nothing reported on the crash.

2 questions

1. IS there a way to look at why it is crashing on my phone
2. Any idea why it would stop working once installed from the App Store when it must have worked for apple when they tested it and worked for me as well before on the App Store?

Comment: Retrieve the crash log from your iPhone and symbolicate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579117/how-to-symbolicate-crash-error-logs-from-a-xamarin-forms-ios-project  (FYI: Assuming you are not using a crash reporter within your app, but you should be  )

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was mistaken about the restore failing. Well, it is failing, but the reason it is failing is because the backup is failing on each record, so nothing is created on iCloud to be read by the restore code. I have asked on a couple channels for help on what to do for writing to iCloud when the code is built in release mode, but have yet to receive any help. My code works perfectly in Debug, just not in release mode.