# How can I solve the crash report from App Store?

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash

So I've been programming a Xamarin app that I want to have available on the App Store. However, I have already submitted it twice with rejections concerning a crash when the app is played on devices of any version. The app works perfectly fine, along with all the simulators. I also looked at the crash log but didn't find any. But app store is getting the app crash during launch.

Thanks for the help.

[Crash Log Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF4kG.png)

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579117/how-to-symbolicate-crash-error-logs-from-a-xamarin-forms-ios-project

Answer (score 2):

Your crashlog screenshot does not reveal anything, but I'm guessing that your app is crashing in release mode which you have not tested. You probably built and tested it in debug mode?

So for starters, try to launch the app to device and simulator in **release** mode and inspect device logs then

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I double checked the app.It didn't crashed in both debug and release mode.
Crashlog from app store - https://iosapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/Purple124/v4/ee/c8/02/eec802ee-1619-5bf7-0410-fb239e791add/attachment.crashlog-448CB314-5DB6-4EE6-BE8D-6DC44DE3099D.txt?accessKey=1608194148_6643494152095981973_uG3xLJXUEuwDN%2FaTJc90rB6zakcRwSk0ikWE%2F%2FlSPKqAsYDZ%2FVjV5aKTOcIvZ48n0FTrUYckMAYxBzpZFAYzjAXS6jLNmcOwiYa6qDBsqU13GEHDE5bd1UlFDTQdK9eS%2FZs9ey%2Be59A0X76oY7CQDt7Ci534k0GNhvOCl4kzfjeWT242pa5yriqLsw2qnZZfK9gNeaFWtVqz3mn%2BITN3E8GpvOwGs%2F7WNjRnugqYbB0%3D